# Gulp task finishing too early

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, gulp

I am struggling with my gulp script exiting too early.

I narrowed down the problem to this:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var through = require("through2");

function Transform() {
    return through.obj(function(file,enc,next) {
        // not calling next(null,file)
    });
}

gulp.task("test",function() {
    return gulp.src("foo")
        .pipe(Transform())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("tmp"));
});
```

Running `gulp test`, i would expect gulp never to exit since the stream should be blocked in the `Transform` operation that never pass the file down. But it returns.

There is obviously something i missed. What is it ?

Comment: Why don't you call `next` Also the anonymous function does return even if you don't call `return` explicitly. In this case it returns `undefined`?

Comment: The sample code is to show the issue, this is on purpose i do not call `next`. 

In my real scenario, i would call it after the job that is to be done in `Transform` is complete, but gulp exits before `next` is called.

Comment: I am totally aware that the anonymous function returns `undefined`, but in my understanding (which is apparently wrong), since the file is not passed down, the stream should remain open and gulp should not exit.